# How to find the bounds of a TypeMirror & turn them into a JavaPoet TypeSpec?

Tags: java, annotation-processing, javapoet

I have an annotation processor that takes an annotated class and attempts to create a subclass of it:

```
package test;

import com.squareup.javapoet.ClassName;
import com.squareup.javapoet.JavaFile;
import com.squareup.javapoet.TypeSpec;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.annotation.processing.AbstractProcessor;
import javax.annotation.processing.ProcessingEnvironment;
import javax.annotation.processing.RoundEnvironment;
import javax.annotation.processing.SupportedAnnotationTypes;
import javax.annotation.processing.SupportedSourceVersion;
import javax.lang.model.SourceVersion;
import javax.lang.model.element.Element;
import javax.lang.model.element.Modifier;
import javax.lang.model.element.TypeElement;

@SupportedAnnotationTypes("java.lang.SuppressWarnings")
@SupportedSourceVersion(SourceVersion.RELEASE_7)
public class BSProcessor extends AbstractProcessor {
    @Override
    public synchronized void init(ProcessingEnvironment processingEnv) {
        super.init(processingEnv);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations, RoundEnvironment roundEnvironment) {
        for (TypeElement baseClassAnnotation : annotations) {
            for (Element annotatedElement : roundEnvironment.getElementsAnnotatedWith(baseClassAnnotation)) {
                handleAnnotatedTypeElement((TypeElement) annotatedElement);
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void handleAnnotatedTypeElement(TypeElement annotatedTypeElement) {
        try {
            javaFile(annotatedTypeElement).writeTo(System.out);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private JavaFile javaFile(TypeElement annotatedTypeElement) {
        return JavaFile.builder(packageName(annotatedTypeElement), typeSpec(annotatedTypeElement))
                .build();
    }

    private TypeSpec typeSpec(TypeElement annotatedTypeElement) {
        return TypeSpec.classBuilder(className(annotatedTypeElement))
                .addModifiers(Modifier.PUBLIC, Modifier.ABSTRACT)
                .build();
    }

    private ClassName className(TypeElement annotatedTypeElement) {
        return ClassName.get(packageName(annotatedTypeElement), String.format("AutoGenerated_%s",
                annotatedTypeElement.getSimpleName()));
    }

    private String packageName(TypeElement annotatedTypeElement) {
        return annotatedTypeElement.getEnclosingElement().toString();
    }
}
```

This works with classes without type parameters, but I'm not sure how to do so with them. Performing `toString` on the type variables will only give the variable name, not the bounds too. Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type parameters of `TypeElement` can be retrieved by calling `getTypeParameters()` and their bounds can be obtained by calling `getBounds()` on obtained `TypeParameterElement`s. I am assuming, that you are troubled over the following step — which concrete types should be passed to those type parameters to satisfy those bounds.

Unfortunately, this is a problem, that can not be easily solved for *arbitrary* type (which is what you seems to be after). For example, look at this type:

```
public abstract class Recursive<UU extends Callable<UU>> {
}
```

You may intuitively conclude, that it can be implemented by a class like this:

```
public class Solution extends Recursive<Solution> implements Callable<Solution> {
  @Override
  public Solution call() throws Exception {
    return new Solution();
  }
}
```

but that's not trivial to automate, and you (probably) do not want to include required machinery in your code.

Instead of trying to solve that problem yourself, I recommend you to take advantage of type erasure and let compiler solve the problem for you:

```
// returns something like "Map<K, V>", this is NOT what you want!
DeclaredType classType = (DeclaredType) typeElement.asType();

Types types = processingEnvironment.getTypeUtils();
Elements elements = processingEnvironment.getElementUtils();

// this obtains raw type (plain "Map"), with all methods type-erased,
// the compiler is much better at solving type riddles than you!
DeclaredType rawType = types.getDeclaredType(typeElement);

final Collection<? extends ExecutableElement> methods =
    ElementFilter.methodsIn(elements.getAllMembers(typeElement));

// To create a MethodSpec, suitable for the raw type, you should 
// call 3-parameter MethodSpec#overriding with type-erased raw class type
// as second parameter and javax.lang.model.util.Types instance as third
MethodSpec newMethod = MethodSpec.overriding(methods.get(0), rawType, types);
```

As such, the answer to your specific question is "don't pass any type parameters to JavaPoet, use raw types".

Comment: Thanks. Helped a lot!